# While loop confusion

Tags: c++, while-loop, sfml

### Question:

My while loop is not exiting. During debugging it has says very specifically that `stateID` is equal to 3. However, when I add `std::cout << stateID;` the value `1` is always written to the console, no matter what the debugger is telling me.

In the code, I render the screen *after* the input loop. This shows that, without a doubt, the input loop exits properly, as expected. Also, if that is not enough, It would have to exit for the stateID to change in the first place. Please, no more discussion of the nested loop being the issue. And I have also used breakpoints after the loop which are properly hit.

### Code:

```
int main()
{

    stateID = 1;

    GameState* state = new GameStateTitle();

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600), "RPG");

    //GAME LOOP//
    while (stateID != 3)
    {//INPUT//
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        //Window closed
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            set_next_state(3);
            break;
        }
    }

        change_state(state);

    //RENDERING//
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    state->render(window);

    window.display();
    }
    /////////////

    window.close();

    return 0;
}

void set_next_state(int new_state)
{
    //Set the next state to take place
    next_state = new_state;
}

void change_state(GameState *current_state)
{
    //Check if the next state is null or exit
    if (next_state != 0)
    {
        if (next_state != 3)
            delete current_state;

        //Set the new state
        switch(next_state)
                ...
        }

        stateID = next_state;
        next_state = 0;
    }
}
```

## Below is my full code, in case I missed something important.

### Main.cpp

```
#include "GameState.hpp"

int main()
{

    stateID = STATE_TITLE;

    GameState* state = new GameStateTitle();

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600), "RPG");

    //GAME LOOP//
    while (stateID != STATE_EXIT)
    {
        //INPUT//
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            //Window closed
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                set_next_state(STATE_EXIT);
                break;
            }
        }
        ///////////

        ////LOGIC//
        state->logic();
        ///////////

        change_state(state);

        //RENDERING//
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        state->render(window);

        std::cout << stateID;

        window.display();
        /////////////
    }
    ///////////////

    window.close();

    return 0;
}
```

### GameState.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

//DEFINITIONS ETC//
enum GAME_STATES {
    STATE_NULL,
    STATE_TITLE,
    STATE_BATTLE,
    STATE_EXIT
};
///////////////////

//Game State Class//
class GameState
{
public:
    virtual void input(void) = 0;
    virtual void logic(void) = 0;
    virtual void render(sf::RenderWindow &window) = 0;
};
////////////////////

//FUNCTIONS//
void set_next_state(int new_state);
void change_state(GameState *current_state);
/////////////

//VARIABLES//
static int stateID;
static int next_state;
/////////////

//Title GameState Class//
class GameStateTitle : public GameState
{
private:
    sf::Texture img_title;
    sf::Sprite bgr_title;

public:
    GameStateTitle(void);
    ~GameStateTitle(void);

    void input(void);
    void logic(void);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow &window);
};
/////////////////////////

//Battle GameState Class//
class GameStateBattle : public GameState
{
private:
    sf::Image img_left;
    sf::Image img_right;

public:
    GameStateBattle(void);
    ~GameStateBattle(void);

    void input(void);
    void logic(void);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow &window);
};
//////////////////////////
```

### GameState.cpp

```
#include "GameState.hpp"

//Game state general functions
void set_next_state(int new_state)
{
    //Set the next state to take place
    next_state = new_state;
}

void change_state(GameState *current_state)
{
    //Check if the next state is null or exit
    if (next_state != STATE_NULL)
    {
        if (next_state != STATE_EXIT)
            delete current_state;

        //Set the new state
        switch(next_state)
        {
        case STATE_TITLE:
            current_state = new GameStateTitle;
            break;
        case STATE_BATTLE:
            current_state = new GameStateBattle;
            break;
        }

        stateID = next_state;
        next_state = STATE_NULL;
    }
}

//The functions of the title state
GameStateTitle::GameStateTitle(void)
{
    //Load texture
    img_title.loadFromFile("title_screen.png");

    //Set texture to background
    bgr_title.setTexture(img_title);
}

GameStateTitle::~GameStateTitle(void)
{
}

void GameStateTitle::input(void)
{
}

void GameStateTitle::logic(void)
{
}

void GameStateTitle::render(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    window.draw(bgr_title);
}

//The functions of the battle state
GameStateBattle::GameStateBattle(void)
{
}

GameStateBattle::~GameStateBattle(void)
{
}

void GameStateBattle::input(void)
{
}

void GameStateBattle::logic(void)
{
}

void GameStateBattle::render(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi jim, first, put a flag for SFML.

Comment: Yes -- this sounds like a problem wherein you're updating a different variable local to some other function that also is called `stateID`, rather than updating the one you're actually checking.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same `stateID` variable?  Maybe add some code to print `stateID` right after the call to `change_state`.

Comment: Like stated in the question, while debugging, it says that the `stateID` variable that the `while` loop is based on is equal to 3. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't need to print anything because my debugger tells me the value.

Comment: The window.poolEvent is an infinite loop to get the events. When you do a break inside the switch you get out of the switch, so the loops continues. You need to change your while or do another break outside the switch

Comment: @Jim Hurley: Well, **which** loop does not quit??? You have two nested loops in your code. Did you figure which one does not want to quit? This is what you should start from.

Comment: Yes. I updated the code to show that I also render the screen. The screen renders properly. The main while loop is the problem, it continues to loop. The input loop quits properly.

Comment: Occasionally, the debugger can be confused. If you want to be 100% sure, put an output in there.

Comment: @Angew: You were right; I used a `cout` and changed it to a console app, and the output for stateID was _always_ 1, even when the debugger told me 3.

Comment: I apologize for those who tried to find an answer, it turns out the problem wasn't in the original code I had posted.

Answer (score 5):

You have two `while` loops. The condition in the outer while will never be tested until the inner loop exits.

Consider using just one loop, with a single condition.

```
sf::Event event;
while ( (stateID != 3) && window.pollEvent(event)) {

}
```

Comment: They are two separate loops. The inner one _does_ exit. That is not the problem. Read updated question.

Comment: Yes, thats the better approach, "what Jim wants is an and operation that way (inner while) it looks more like an or operation", so if one of those two changes it get out of the loop

Comment: This answer is undeserving of the upvotes, he clearly did not read/understand the problem.

Comment: @JimHurley - With the nested loops, have you set a breakpoint in a debugger to verify that the inner loop is exiting when you think? Also, could you post the declarations of stateID and the definitions of set_next_state? Finally, note that if you use a single loop, you eliminate entirely the risk that the outer condition is never being tested.

Comment: Yes, I did set a breakpoint. Although, if you read the question, you would know that it was unnecessary. And for your second question, no. If I did so, the loop would exit immediately. pollEvent returns false if there is no user input.

Comment: Worst case, you could debug-print. But are you really prevented from setting a breakpoint *after* the inner loop? Jim, I've read your question, and I hear your certainty that the inner loop exits. I've found that when something doesn't work as I expect, it's useful to verify assumptions, including those I'm certain about.

Comment: I did set a breakpoint after the inner loop. I'm sorry if I sound rude, I'm just frustrated.

Comment: In fact, I set a break loop in all of my functions to make sure they are all being called properly, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking out of the `switch` and not out of the `while`.

The program below (attempts to) duplicate your code.
It works as expected, with both loops ending when they are supposed to.

Btw, this is what we call a [short, contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/).
Correct as in compilable, using globals such as `stateID` or magic numbers such as the `3` in `while (stateID != 3)` is bad form and not the mark of a professional.

How does your program deviate from the one below?

```
#define STATE_TITLE 2
#define STATE_BATTLE 3
#define STATE_NULL 0

int stateID;
int next_state;

struct Event
{
    Event(int Num) : type(Num){}

    Event() : type( 5 ){} // random number grater than 1

    enum Type
    {
        Closed = 1 // equivalent to sf::Event::Closed
    };

    int type;
};

class Window
{
public:

    int pollEvent( Event& Ev )
    {
        return --Ev.type;
    }
};

void set_next_state(int new_state)
{
    next_state = new_state;
}

void change_state()
{
    if (next_state != STATE_NULL)
    {
        stateID = next_state;
        next_state = STATE_NULL;
    }
}

int _tmain()
{
    stateID = STATE_TITLE;

    Window window;

    //GAME LOOP//
    while (stateID != 3)
    {//INPUT//
        Event event;
        // note that there is at least one event with a Closed type before window.pollEvent(event) return false (0)
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                //Window closed
            case Event::Closed:
                set_next_state(3);
                break;
            }
        }

        change_state();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if theire is no event should he not change the state with change_state()?

Comment: I'm not attempting to break out of the while. The function `set_next_state` changes `stateID` to 3. That should make the loop quit.

Comment: @JimHurley Does `window.pollEvent(event)` ever return `false` to make the inner loop end?

Comment: @JimHurley I have posted a simpler version of your code which works fine. Check how it differs from yours.

Comment: _I want the `pollEvent` loop to return false._ There are other things I want to do in the main loop other than wait for the user to quit. You are not addressing my problem, just completely changing my code. I have told you what is wrong. I need you to help me fix that under _my conditions_, not write new code that solves the problem in a way that completely changes my program. `pollEvent` is a function of `SFML`. It works how it is supposed to.

Comment: Also, in direct response to your new code, I have used breakpoints in the function `change_state` to prove that it properly recognizes the close event.

Comment: @JimHurley Perhaps it's time you took a short break. *I did not change your code.* I have just added code that provides similar behaviur to the SFML code. "I want the pollEvent loop to return false" doesn't make sense, loops don't return *anything*. Compare, under the debugger the behaviour of your code and that of mine. See where it differs. In particular, change the Event ctor to initialize `type` to 1, the `pollEvent` loop will not be executed, the state will not change and the outer loop will run forever.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31005/discussion-between-andrei-and-jim-hurley)

Comment: I apologize if I misspoke. When I said "I want the `pollEvent` loop to return false," I meant I wanted pollEvent to return false so the loop would exit. When you said "// note that there is at least one event with a Closed type before window.pollEvent(event) return false (0)" I assumed that meant `pollEvent` didn't return false until an event took place. What did you mean by that, if not what I previously thought?

Comment: @JimHurley there's a chat link in the comment above

Comment: Not necessary, I figured out the issue. It had something to do with the declaration and usage of stateID in my full code. I am going to remove this question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function `change_state` to the following:

```
void change_state(GameState *current_state, int &ID)
{
    //Check if the next state is null or exit
    if (next_state != STATE_NULL)
    {
        if (next_state != STATE_EXIT)
            delete current_state;

        //Set the new state
        switch(next_state)
        {
        case STATE_TITLE:
            current_state = new GameStateTitle;
            break;
        case STATE_BATTLE:
            current_state = new GameStateBattle;
            break;
        }

        ID = next_state;
        next_state = STATE_NULL;
    }
}
```

The issue must've been within the declaration of `stateID`, because it was never being changed in this function.